# Vesta CP and RoundCube Mail database error

Tags: php, ssh, vps, roundcube, vesta

Hello all i am having a vps server with vesta installes but i am having database connection error with roundcube here ..
[image]

I read this article https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=4375
and helped me to understand the issue 
And the solution is

This issue appeared for me because roundcubemail wasn't fully installed and configured during the Vesta install process. To get it working I needed to set the following line to true instead of false in /etc/roundcubemail/main.inc.php:

```
   CODE: SELECT ALL
    $rcmail_config['enable_installer'] = false;
```

Then run the roundcubemail installer by going to http://domain.org/webmail/installer/

And to complete the installer successfully after I got to the point that it complained that I had no readable config.inc.php I needed to copy the config.inc.php the installer generated into /etc/roundcubemail/ and set that file to the same readability as the other config files in that directory and then set the same option:

```
       CODE: SELECT ALL
       $rcmail_config['enable_installer'] = false;
```

once again to true, but in the new file config.inc.php rather than /etc/roundcubemail/main.inc.php.

The installation then completed correctly and at that point I set the enable_installer lines I referenced above back to false in both

> /etc/roundcubemail/main.inc.php

and in /etc/roundcubemail/config.inc.php so that they would no longer be in installer mode. Not sure if this is a Vesta bug – my understanding was that dependencies like Roundcubemail would be completely installed and configured in the Vesta install process but maybe that's incorrect.

but i dont know how to access the etc folder from my server by ssh
As when i login i only see thse when ls

```
     f.txt  login.info  vst-install-rhel.sh  vst-install.sh  vst_install_backups
```

and when entered into vst_install_backups i get these

```
 clamd  dovecot  exim  httpd  mongodb  mysql  named  nginx  php  php-fpm  postgresql  proftpd  spamassassin  vesta  vsftpd
```

Please help me solve the roundcube and vesta issue ..

Comment: Mate, could you solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have just same problem. I have solved it by next steps:

1) Login in phpmyadmin under root (password for root should be same as for vesta). 
2) Create database roundcube
3) Create user roundcube with privilegies

```
CREATE USER 'roundcube'@'localhost';

SET PASSWORD FOR roundcube@localhost = PASSWORD('<password>');

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON roundcube.* TO roundcube@localhost;
```

you can find password there: /etc/roundcube/db.inc.php

4) Login by ssh to the server and run script:

```
mysql roundcube < /usr/share/dbconfig-common/data/roundcube/install/mysql
```

This is sql from installation of vesta

Comment: For me, the path was `/usr/share/roundcube/SQL/mysql.initial.sql`.